# how to create RadioButton and edittext for setText of radio button from user for an android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want user to determine the number of Radio Buttons to be inserted 
at the run time.
User will also setText for radio buttons after running an application
I tried few things but didnt workout.
I tried defining TextView with id txtt in loop for accepting input while creating radio buttons.
But just getting some random numbers as a SetText for RadioButtons.
Any help is appreciated.
Here is my .xml file..

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" />


       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter no."
        android:inputType="number" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter details"
        android:inputType="text" />

      <Button

        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create List Of Voting Candidates" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java file

```
 package com.vik.countmyvote.activities;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.vik.countmyvote.R;

    public class TryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_try);



        final EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_no);

        findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                int number=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                addRadioButtons(number);
            }
        });

    }
    int k=1;

    public void addRadioButtons(int number) {

        for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
            RadioGroup ll = new RadioGroup(this);


            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
                TextView txtt = new TextView(this);
                 String editText1= String.valueOf(R.id.txtt);
                String textt=editText1;
                rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + k);
                rdbtn.setText(textt);
                ll.addView(rdbtn);k++;
            }
            ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: You say "But just getting some random numbers as a SetText for RadioButtons".  What text do you want on each radio button?

Comment: That text will be entered by user at run time

Comment: Also it is very unclear exactly what your question is.  What problem is it that you are asking for help with?  Your statement about "random numbers as SetText for RadioButtons" is the closest thing I see to an actual problem statement.

Comment: If, as you say, "the text will be set by the user at runtime", why are you putting the ID of the string resource on each radio button?

Comment: In that text box with id txtt user will enter the input which he wants to set for radio button

Comment: So I will ask again - what exactly is your question?

Comment: See suppose im making a poll app.

Comment: its a offline app, user will decide how many options he wants when he runs app

Comment: You still have not asked a question.

Comment: and will also set text for those Radio buttons when he'll run the app

Comment: how to code radio buttons in a way that it will be dynamic and text for radio buttons will set according to user? @EJK

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout (or a ConstraintLayout) instead of a LinearLayout. Anchor your RadioGroup to the top and the rest to the bottom (well, the Button to the bottom and the other ones on top of each other, on top of the Button).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using adapter ,in adapter view take radio button and Edit Text  to set Text in edit text. you can make a view at runtime according your number of view.

this problem help me to make Radio Button and Edit Text At runtime.

Comment: can you provide more details?